# Day selection in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have requirement in which i am storing date in the database. But I only want allow the user to change the day for the select date.

Like they can only select Monday , Tuesday etc and based on that I want adjust the date in database.

To meet the requirement , I am trying the following code and it is throwing error

```
<%= f.datetime_select :published_at.to_time.strftime("%a") %>
```

Following is the error message:

```
NoMethodError in Articles#new 

Showing C:/Users/huzaifa.gain/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/blog/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb where line #32 raised: 
undefined method `to_time' for :published_at:Symbol 

Extracted source (around line #32): 
29:   </div>
30:   <div class="field">
31:     <%= f.label :published_at %><br />
32:     <%= f.datetime_select :published_at.to_time.strftime("%a") %>
33:     <%= f.select :published_at, Date::DAYNAMES.zip((0..6).to_a) %> 
34: 
35:
```

Comment: whats the format of your `published_at` column? and what do you have on the constant?

Comment: published_ is a datetime field

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :published_at.to_strftime("%a") %>
```

Comment: I am seeing error :undefined method `to_strftime' for :published_at:Symbol

Answer (score 0):

datetime_select and other form helpers are methods on the formbuilder objects. You need to think about what options this helper takes. It does not seem to support strftime. Refer [the api reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select) for the options.